# Javascript - Index inside a for reader into a for inside a function, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, scope

javascript:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ 
    v = fn(obj); 
}

function fn(o)
{
    for(i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
    { 
        ... 
    }
}
```

The first index get modify from second FOR inside the function fn(o);
How is it possible? what's the scope of index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're declaring `i` as a local variable, so what's happening is that `i` being treated as a global variable. You need to write the `var` keyword in order for a variable to become a local variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ 
    v = fn(obj); 
}

function fn(o)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
    { 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `var` so it looks like you're not `var`ing anything, but I'll add those in and answer the question

> Is it possible to modify the `i` in one `for` loop from another in a different scope?

When using *functions* in *JavaScript*, all primitive arguments are passed *ByVal* and all object arguments are passed *ByRef*. This also happens when using `=`.

Therefore, if you want to modify `i` out-of-scope, you will need to always access it through an *Object*.

```
function foo() { // scope this away from fn
    for (var c = {i: 0}; c.i < n; c.i++) { // i wrapped in object
        v = fn(obj, c); // pass wrapping object into `fn`, too. Now see `fn`
        // c.i is now the result of change in `fn`
    }
}

function fn(o, c) {
    for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) { 
            // ... 
    }
    // make change to c.i
    c.i = 0;
}

foo();
```

Comment: I realise your question is really asking _why_ it's happening in your code (the variable name conflict), but it was said in a vague enough way to possibly be asking _how_ to achieve it in a desirable way.